# how to give command to printer without user interaction (without print dialog)

Tags: php, printing

I am creating an application in PHP and want to give a command to a printer but problem is that there are more than two printers and I want to give the command to a different printer by clicking on different button without the print dialog.

Comment: This is an online app? Sorry, but you can't force printing without the print dialog.

Comment: Where do you want to print from? A web server (to a printer on the server's LAN), a web browser (to a printer on the user's LAN), or a standalone application, maybe command line or GTK, (to a printer on the same LAN as the program).

Comment: hi, it is a web application and there is more than two printer on lan, basically i am creating a restaurant application where user choose item from their table where touch panel pc is used and they set order, which will print on a particular printer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
printer_list()
```

function to get list of printers attached to server, and then use:

```
printer_open
```

to open connection to printer providing printer name as parameter to the function.
I hope that helps you to some extent

Answer (score 0):

In online web applications you can't.

A workaround could be to write `Java Applet` or in `IE` you can do this via `ActiveX` controls.